# perl WWW::Mechanize file upload error

Tags: perl, mechanize

I've faced a weird problem with WWW::Mechanize module, the php test uploader code:

```
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="70"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';
if( $_POST['_upl'] == "Upload" )
{
if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']))
{
echo '<b>Upload success.</b><br>';
        } else {
 echo '<b>Upload faild.</b><br>';
        }
}
?>
```

the perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
$path = 'http://path/to/uploader-code.php';
$file = $ARGV[0];
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(show_progress => 1);
            $mech->get($path);
            $mech->submit_form(
                form_name => 'uploader',
                fields =>
                {
                    '_upl' => 'Upload',
                    'file' => $file
                }
            );
```

I got this output on the command line:

```
** GET http://path/to/uploader-code.php ==> 200 OK (3s)
** POST http://path/to/uploader-code.php ==> 200 OK (3s)
```

From the browser I'm able to upload without any problem, but with mechanize it faild. I'm using windows 8, activeperl lastest version.

Comment: Maybe use this one instead of perl WWW::Mechanize => http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/

Comment: @GarciaPL I can't rewrite all the project with snoopy, that's just a part of the upload sub for the project. Thanks.

Comment: You should `use warnings/strict` if you’re not already. Try `die "No such file $file\n" unless -e $file;` — might not be where/what you think. Then try checking what `$mech->content` looks like; page might tell you what’s wrong. Then use the Network panel of browser debugger to see what exact headers being sent, perhaps you’re missing some.

Comment: What error are you getting? You say that it failed, but not what happened instead.

Comment: Thanks all, it don't show any error, it look like the cause is `$_POST['_upl'] == "Upload"`. I've edited the php code and the problem is sloved.